# Selenium - Element is Not Visible [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, visible

I'm currently in CH11 from the "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" book and I'm going over the `Selenium` module. I'm trying to move to the end of a page but I'm getting some problems. I also tried to look similar problems in this site and tried the solutions suggested without success unfortunately. Here's my code, when I type it into the IDLE Shell:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser= webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://nostarch.com')
htmlElem= browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
type(htmlElem)
<class 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement'>
htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.END)  # Error
```

Exception -:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.END)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not visible
```

Apparently the `html` element is not visible? I don't understand how so since it seems to locates the `html` element just fine as seen on the code without any problems but the `Key.ENTER` is where I'm getting the error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try locating the element by some other attribute ?

Comment: Try `browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')`. This works for me

Comment: Thanks a lot Andersson, it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested the following with Chrome driver and it works (It should also work with Firefox):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://nostarch.com')
body_elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body_elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: Thanks @ettanany it's working now. Do you know why it didn't worked with 'html' though?